# getting specific median from data

Tags: python, pandas, max

I have a `DataFrame` with columns `time`, `latitude`, and `longitude`. It looks like this:

```
>>> df.head()
                  time   latitude  longitude
0  2011-12-16 08:09:07  42.386391 -71.013544
1  2011-12-16 08:09:08  42.386391 -71.013544
2  2011-12-16 08:09:09  42.386391 -71.013544
3  2011-12-16 08:09:10  42.386391 -71.013544
4  2011-12-16 08:09:11  42.386391 -71.013544
```

What I am trying to do, is estimate where a person lives. The easiest way to do this is to get the mode (most common) of their location at the earliest moments in the day.

My dataframe has over 700,000 rows and spans about 3 months with data from 4-8 hours a day every second! So what I need to do is find the most common (latitude,longitude) pairs from the first couple seconds of each day.

If I wanted to use the whole dataset rather than just the first couple seconds of each day, I could do the following:

```
l = []
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    l.append((df.latitude[i],df.longitude[i]))
import collections
answer = collections.Counter(l).most_common(1)
```

That may or may not be the most efficient way, and if you have a better way that will work, feel free to use that in your answer. The important part of this is that I **only** take the first couple values from each day.

Thank you.

**note: The starting time for each day varies.**

Comment: actually the *mode* is the most common value in a data set. the median is the value that half that values are less than and half are greater than. integral from -infinity to m where m is the median is 1/2

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, I am using hours here, but same idea
Groupby the date, then 
Your function return the median of the first 3 values (or less if there are less)

```
In [23]: df = DataFrame(randn(2000,2),
        index=date_range('20130101',periods=2000,freq='H'))

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 2000 entries, 2013-01-01 00:00:00 to 2013-03-25 07:00:00
Freq: H
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    2000  non-null values
1    2000  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2)

In [21]: def f(frame):
   ....:     if len(frame) > 3:
   ....:         frame = frame.iloc[0:4,:]
   ....:     return frame.median()
   ....: 


In [25]: df.resample('D',how=f).head(20)
Out[25]: 
                   0         1
2013-01-01 -1.168960  0.752771
2013-01-02  0.252991  0.257350
2013-01-03  0.823164  0.246403
2013-01-04 -0.253409 -0.099833
2013-01-05  0.328023 -0.308967
2013-01-06 -0.086218 -1.090935
2013-01-07  0.073870  0.256468
2013-01-08 -0.551869  0.332902
2013-01-09  0.267126  0.232623
2013-01-10  0.305948  0.460094
2013-01-11 -0.088975 -1.080070
2013-01-12 -0.587940  0.391419
2013-01-13 -0.220146  0.380210
2013-01-14 -0.689020 -0.873559
2013-01-15  0.576461 -0.184413
2013-01-16  0.258620  0.221407
2013-01-17 -0.385102  0.376829
2013-01-18  0.096542  0.331183
2013-01-19  0.385703  0.241587
2013-01-20 -1.119306 -0.210429
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the median start-of-day location in one line.

```
df.set_index('time').resample('D', how='first').median()
```

This consider only the first position each day, not the first few, but if samples are taken every second, it seems to me that the first position and the first several positions are likely to be about the same.

Comment: this suggests a feature: ``.resample('D', how='range', start=0, stop=3).median()``

Comment: Neat suggestion. Maybe I'll make a PR.

Comment: its kind of like your ``filter`` PR, but in this case a ``BinFilter`` (as opposed to a ``ValueFilter``)

Comment: actually I looked at your PR again, I think that if you used my function (and your filter) it might work directly

Comment: Trying that out now. I find ``lambda d: d.date()`` is very slow compared to resample('D'). Maybe it's worth adding ``how='range'``.

Comment: forgot you can just: ``df.resample('D',how=f)``

Comment: when I use your code I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 234, in resample
    return sampler.resample(self)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 100, in resample
    raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex')
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex`

Comment: @Ryan, you can only use resample when the index is time-based. @Jeff means ``df.set_index('time').resample('D', how=f)``.

Comment: @RyanSaxe dan is correct, I had created mine that way (do ``set_index`` first)